# How can I group ANDs and ORs in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a method like the following in my Repository class:

```
findByIdAndMessageTypeLikeOrMessageTypeLike(int id, String a, String b);
```

Basically what I am trying to find is all entities where id is `id` and (message type is like either `a` or `b`).

However, what I am getting is: (All entities with id `id` and message type like `a`) AND (all entities where message type like `b`).

I tried `matchesRegex` and using only one String parameter, but I got: `Unsupported keyword REGEX (1): [MatchesRegex, Matches, Regex];`

Is there any way to group ANDs and ORs in JPARepository methods?

Comment: Choose a decent name for the method, and annotate it with `@Query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, the following seems to work:

```
findByIdAndMessageTypeLikeOrByIdAndMessageTypeLike(int id, String a, int id, String b);
```